# How to append 2 pandas dataframes in python and convert to a JSON object where each of the dataframes is self contained in JSON?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes with the same columns. I would like to return them in a single JSON object.

The format for this json object should be

```
{{"dataframe1": 
      {"Date": ,
      "Name": ,
      "ID": }},
{"dataframe2":
      {"Date": ,
      "Name": ,
      "ID": }
}}
```

I have tried:

```
json_str_1 = df1.to_json(orient="records", date_unit="ms")
json_str_2 = df2.to_json(orient="records", date_unit="ms")
return jsonify( dataframe1 = json.loads(json_str_1), dataframe2 = json.loads(json_str_2))
```

But I get a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!